# Why is my js to create raining bowties not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a project where I need to make an html canvas with raining bowtie images. Here is my js:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let img = new Image("images.png")
var ok2animate = true;
img.onload = function(){
function Drop() {
    this.x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - 20);
    this.y = -Math.random() * 20;
    this.fallRate = Math.random()*.5+.5;
}
//
Drop.prototype.draw = function () {
  //   this.x;
  // this.y;
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y)
    return (this);
}
//
Drop.prototype.fall = function () {
    this.y += this.fallRate;
    return (this);
}

function animate() {

    // request another animation frame
    if (ok2animate) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // make all drops fall and then redraw them
    
    for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
        drops[i].fall().draw();
    }

}





// an array of objects each representing 1 drop
var drops = [];

// add some test drops
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    drops.push(new Drop());
}
setInterval(function(){requestAnimationFrame(animate)}, 1000)
requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I make it so the images rain down at 1 second intervals?
(I have included the image file in the same folder)
I have tried using an image file from the web, using a bigger canvas, uwing other versions of jquery, but none of those worked.

Comment: Inside the `animate` function you immediately call `animate` again to go in a recursive loop. It prevents `setInterval` from actually calling `animate` every second. Same goes for the `requestAnimationFrame(animate)` at the end of your code.

Comment: I also see the problem that you’re calling the `draw` method several times in quick succession. This way, you create a bunch of `new Image("images.png")` objects, which is quite wasteful. You also never wait for the image to be loaded (i.e. never wait for the `load` event). It’s probably better to switch to the [`class`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax and create a single private field `#image = new Image("images.png");` that you can refer to using `this.#image`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added onload events for it, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Image creation

You can create a new image with the [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) constructor. You already did that, however, the arguments that the constructor accepts are the `width` and the `height` of the image, not the url. You need the `src` property of the image to reference the image file.

And since you only use 1 single image, that isn't changing, you only have to create and load it once. You can reuse the same image for as many times as you want.

### Starting the loop

Now, you need to start the loop *after* all the images (which in  this case is one) has been loaded. Listen for the `onload` event on the image and call the `setInterval` function whenever the image is loaded.
`setInterval` will start of the rendering here, so there is no need to call `requestAnimationFrame(animate)` anywhere else.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create the image like this.
const image = new Image(100, 100);
image.src = "https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100";

function Drop() {
  this.x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - 20);
  this.y = -Math.random() * 20;
  this.fallRate = Math.random() * 10 + 0.5;
}

Drop.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y)
  return this;
}

Drop.prototype.fall = function() {
  this.y += this.fallRate;
  return this;
}

const drops = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  drops.push(new Drop());
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  for (const drop of drops) {
    drop.fall().draw();
  }
}

image.onload = () => {
  setInterval(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }, 1000)
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```